# Simple document repository

Tags: lamp, document-management

Please recommend me a simple web-based document repository for keeping my small company documents (.DOCs, .PDFs) so i can access them from everywhere. There are many available on the internet, but they are heavy and filled with unnecessary features and requirements.

I have little requirements: pleasant interface (AJAX feels nice), folders or tags, maybe versioning, maybe CIFS mounting or batch upload/download, preferably not written in Java (won't be able to host it).

Regards,
Todor

Note - The question submitter is using a LAMP based environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most simple, and probably easiest to set up, would be a Subversion repository, so you can actually store, delete, add, and modify documents from anywhere, and then add ViewVC on top of it so that you can see the different files from a web browser.

Another possible option, although it is a little bit more heavyweight, would be to install Trac. Again, this still uses Subversion, but it has a web-viewer for the repository nicely integrated, as well as a Wiki capability to allow for versioned shared editing of simpler documents. If you need it, Trac also has an issue tracking system, but you don't have to use it if you don't want to.

Also, in addition to the viewing interface being via a web browser, there are many clients for Linux, Mac, and Windows for the Subversion repository itself to allow manipulation of the files. For windows, the best Subversion Gui is TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Is there a possibility for the Windows machines which produce and modify the documents to synchronize with the Subversion server when connection to it is available? Something with a simple GUI?

Comment: @Tilkov didn't mention the kind of documents he wants to store. 
Are they plaintext (source code) or "binary" (odf, xls...) documents? In our company, Clearcase is being literally abused to store tons of word and excel files, many of which are heavily edited (vacation schedules)...
Before implementing SVN, I suggest reading this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.righttool

Comment: @ipip - If you read the question, it _does_ indicate that they are ".DOCs, .PDFs", both of which are more binary in nature than they are plaintext. Also, this answer was posted in 2008, and there are likely many other better solutions available by now. (Google Drive comes to mind)

Answer (score 5):

Check out Dropbox: https://www.getdropbox.com/home.  Multi-platform (win, mac, nix; and accessible on the web), free, and very good execution.  EDIT:  I forgot to mention secure.

Comment: Just to give you a heads up, your url is messed up.

Comment: They don't seem to clearly state their pricing and free storage policy. This exempt from their Terms terrifies me: "Dropbox reserves the right to use our discretion to delete some or all of Your Files so as to reduce your storage space to below 2 GB"

Comment: @tilkov:  2gb is quite a bit of storage for documents.  You would have to have A LOT of them to fill it up.  And, you can buy a subscription for 10gb of space: $9.99/mo or $99.99/yr ($8.25/mo)

Comment: sorry, 50gb of storage not 10gb. if you signed up early when this was in closed beta, you got a 10gb account.  its early :|

Comment: Anders can you edit your original post to correct the hyperlink rather than just putting it in a comment?

Answer (score 3):

If you want versioning, have you considered setting up a subversion (or CVS or whatever you like) repository and syncing to it?  No need for a web interface in that case (though you can set up web repositories too).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is always one that someone else provides and you just get to use their service. [NetDocs provides secure online hosting of documents and other collaborative files.](http://www.netdocuments.com)

If you're convinced that you want to host a solution on a LAMPP stack yourself, then I would recommend setting up Subversion. Its open-source, free and pretty easy to use once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

Thought about Google Docs, but I am more confident hosting the thing myself. The documents may contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Windows based solutions are not my strength. The setup is simple: a LAMP server in my office with publicly accessible IP address and three laptops running Windows XP with OpenOffice and MS Office.

Answer (score 1):

how about a wiki like wikimedia

Answer (score 1):

I would check out knowledgetree: http://www.knowledgetree.com/.  It's a web based document management system.  They have a free community edition.  I evaluated this a couple years ago and it seems to fit what you're looking for nicely.  It versions, allows you to impose process flow, has user restrictions, etc.  Plus, it's usable by someone with absolutely no concept of what a source control system is.

(* I've no affiliation with them for reference *)

Comment: I've already checked their software. Powerful, but it's huge, parts of it are written in different languages. It looks it will be hard to maintain and fix when broken. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

[Google docs](http://docs.google.com/)

Not exactly what you're asking for, but great for creating and sharing documents online.

Answer (score 0):

What about **SharePoint**? Not simple enough?

Comment: I prefer to stay away from Windows based solutions, as i have no experience with them. LAMP is my chosen environment.

Answer (score 0):

What about WSS (Windows SharePoint Services), all you need is SQL Express, and windows with an external connector license, that gives you all of the features you need (except the ajax)...

Alternatively try www.umbraco.org although this is a bit more involved to configure

Answer (score 0):

Windows Sharepoint Services comes with W2k3, and has the features you are looking for.

One very nice thing is the windows explorer integration so that you can interact with document libraries as if they were network/local folders. You don't mention your server infrassturcutre, but you can use AD permissions/groups etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Office Live Workspace](http://workspace.officelive.com/) is free and integrates with office. (I know, your a LAMP shop, I just thought I would put the option out there.)

> Save your documents to the Web—for
>   free!
>  **Access files from anywhere**
>
> View
>   documents from almost any computer
>   with a Web browser
>
> No more flash
>   drives—files are there when and where
>   you need them
>
> Password-protected
>   document sharing; you control who
>   views and edits
>
> Simplified online
>   collaboration; everyone works from the
>   same documents
>
> **Work with programs you
>   know**
>
> Save over 1,000 Microsoft Office
>   documents in one online place
>
> Manage
>   documents in one convenient place
>
> Open
>   and save files from familiar programs
>   like Word, Excel, and PowerPoint
>
> Synchronize contact, task, and event
>   lists with Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Download [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) and give it a try. Its perfect for your requirements. They have a versatile content repository and nice web based UI. You also have the option of running workflows etc.

And well .. the community version is free.

Comment: It appears there are limitations on the newest version, however.  Single subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Docs and/or any other Google service is very risky - it's frequent to lose publication and/or sharing rights of your docs. There seems to be a bug or hack that blocks access to your files - you need to *request a review* in order to have your docs reappear on web-based Google services, and when Google replies with an -error- tag, its proof they have no control on who or what bans your docs from viewing on the web - use with extreme caution.